# Rendering array data in Datatable

Tags: javascript, datatables

I want to display a (large amount) of data stored in an array from the fomrat:

`records = ["First", "Second", "Third", "...", "last"];`

I am using the following javascript to display the data.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable({
  data: records,
  deferRender: true,
  ordering: false,
  columns: [
    { title: "Title" }
    ]
});
} );
```

But when i want to show the results each character is displayed as one row.

If is switch the representation of the `records` to 
`records = [["First"], ["Second"], ["Third"], ["..."], ["last"]];` it is all fine. But I don't want to change the data structure to the last format.

Is there a possibility to render the data without a nested array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it an option to transform the array inplace?:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
   data: records.map(e => [e]),
   deferRender: true,
   ordering: false,
   columns: [
    { title: "Title" }
   ]
});
```

The original array would remain unmodified.

Comment: Well that is indeed an option. I already read through the documentation and haven‘t found any other option.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a possibility to render the data without a nested array?

No. Datatable renders data per row by array index.